# Add Multiple Images as PFFiles to Parse Array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

basically I'm struggling with this:
I installed an FacebookAlbumPicker (https://github.com/OceanLabs/FacebookImagePicker-iOS)

Now I try to upload these Images to my PFObject PFUser.currentUser["images"] which should be an array of PFFiles.
Later I want to retrieve them.

When uploading to parse (just one photo for) it gives me a strange documentation of it:

```
    images:array  => [{"__type":"File","name":"tfss-c5f07d1f-34a3-4041-bc18-e13237abd077-file","url":"http://files.parsetfss.com/f84a8fda-4aff-45dc-b328-8e46987c191f/tfss-c5f07d1f-34a3-4041-bc18-e13237abd077-file"}]
```

How can I access this inside CollectionviewCells now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot store `PFFile`-objects as Array. Create new class in your Parse app like `PhotoObject` and there create column `file`. Then in your `User` class create column `photos` which will be array of pointers to `PhotoObject` class.

And when you want to get images of user you query for `photos`.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm getting the point. Good Explanations, thanks mate!